# How to make headervalue unselectable?

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, struts2

I need that the header value is unselectable.

```
<s:select headerValue="Choose:" label="Choose one(*)"  list="list" listKey="id" listValue="name" name="tab" id="erc"></s:select>
```

I try put

```
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled" value="0">Choose:</option>
```

but it doesn't work.

Please help!

Comment: `s:select` can't work with `option`.

Comment: You can use plain HTML tags and iterate your list with `<s:iterator>` tag.